# Calling DELETE on a table via FromSqlRaw has no effect?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and I'm trying to use FromSqlRaw to delete all records from a table. While it doesn't throw an exception it also has no effect on the table.

I have:

```
db.MyTable.FromSqlRaw("DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable");
```

What am I missing? What I want to avoid is having to fetch all the data from the table before deleting it.

The output log just says:

```
The thread 0x3a44 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Information: Entity Framework Core 5.0.1 initialized 'MyContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
```

Comment: What does the log output say?

Comment: @Marco Nothing useful, I've updated the question with the log output.

Comment: Does it work with [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-3.1)?

Comment: @ChrisYungmann I don't think that's supported anymore. Intellisense is telling me that the database facade doesn't contain a definition for ExecuteSqlCommand.

Comment: Looks like you need NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

Comment: I see you updated your comment, `ExecuteSqlRaw` is working. Thanks! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FromSqlRaw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalQueryableExtensions_FromSqlRaw__1_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbSet___0__System_String_System_Object___) is for queries that return entities. You instead want [`ExecuteSqlRaw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-5.0), which is for queries that do not return entities and can be found in the NuGet package [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/).